# LTSpice SEPIC simulation current spikes

Tags: ltspice, sepic

I am designing a SEPIC power supply using the LT3758. I have simulated the circuit in LTSpice and all the waveforms are as expected except the L1 current.
Here I see massive overshoots when the MOSFET switches on (eg normal current is about 3A pk-pk and overshoot goes up to over 20A). The spike is extremely narrow (< 1nS).

I am new to LTSpice, so might be missing something obvious.

Is this spike real or a simulator aboration? What could be causing it and what can I do about it?

[image: Overshoot]

[image: SEPIC schematic]

Input +28V, Output +40V 1A.

[Edit] I have posted a follow on question here [LTSpice SEPIC design low freq ringing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/209024/ltspice-sepic-design-low-freq-ringing)

Comment: Are you using realistic values for parasitics?

Comment: If you put 0.01 ohms in series with the inductor what happens.

Comment: I see you are using coupled inductors; if you do not use a realistic model (preferably from the manufacturer), your results can contain 'interesting' artefacts. I have had this issue and it mostly disappeared when I used the manufacturers model.

Comment: The V1 source also has 0 resistance. Add the expected ESR of your power source to that.

Comment: And why `V=50` on C5?

Comment: @PlasmaHH please explain?

Comment: @Andy aka the inductors are configured with 8.9mOhms ESR as per datasheet. I tried it at 0.01Ohm and nothing improved.

Comment: @Peter Smith the LT 3758 datasheet says the inductors can be coupled or uncoupled. I had originally tried entering them as uncoupled but ended up putting the coupling statement because it made something look better (can't remember what now). Anyway removing the coupling statement gets rid of the spikes :-) but it does introduce some serious ringing at power up.

Comment: @rdtsc the V=50 is just to remind me the voltage rating required. C4 needs to be 100V but I haven't entered that yet.

Comment: Have you also added parasitic capacitance to the inductor?

Comment: There is 10pF of parallel cap defined on each inductor. This is just a guess.

Comment: Just to prove a point have you tried removing that 10pF capacitance to see what happens in your simulation? Also you say the pulse was less than 1ns but can you be specific? Can you show a better screenshot with a 1ns time base on?

Answer (score 1):

The only place this can come from is stored charge in D1 (or gate drive on Q1, but that's not the case).

Your currents look non-linear with time -- likely your circuit is not very efficient.

Comment: LTSpice claims the circuit is 88% efficient. I had some suspicions about the diode specs but changing the inductor coupling seems to have sorted that problem - see comment above.